# mixing two sensors data in a dataframe regarding timestamp condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to merge some data from different sensors regardin the Timestamp.

I can be done by iterating the dataframe with an if condition on the timestamp, but it's not very efficient.. Does somebody have a better idea ?

Here is a simple example with the result I expect :

The sensor 1 worked correctly until 2018-01-01 02:00:00. The sensor 2 worked correctly from 2018-01-01 03:00:00

```
idx = pd.date_range("2018-01-01", periods=6, freq="H")

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'sensor 1' :[5.4,5,5.2,3,2,2],
    'sensor 2' : [-1,-2,-3,5.5,5.4,5.6]},
    index=idx)

display(df)


#result = "sensor 1 before 2018-01-01 03:00 and sensor 2 after that"

result =  pd.DataFrame(data={
    'sensor' :[5.4,5,5.2,5.5,5.4,5.6]},
    index=idx)

display(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

why not filter by the index?

```
idx = pd.date_range("2018-01-01", periods=6, freq="H")

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'sensor 1' :[5.4,5,5.2,3,2,2],
    'sensor 2' : [-1,-2,-3,5.5,5.4,5.6]},
    index=idx)

date = datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1,02)
sens_1_data = df.loc[df.index <= date]
sens_1_data = sens_1_data[['sensor 1']]
sens_2_data = df.loc[df.index > date]
sens_2_data = sens_1_data[['sensor 2']]
sens_1_data.columns =['sensor']
sens_2_data.columns =['sensor']
sens_data = pd.concat(sens_1_data,sens_2_data)
```